# How can you list the contents of the global namespace from within a module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python, you can type dir() to get a list of the items in the global namespace, but the list is ugly, and it includes both public and private objects.  I want to write a function (say `pretty`) that pretties it up.  My function will live inside a module.

When I call `pretty(dir())` I wind up pretty printing the objects in the module.  Same for `pretty(sorted(globals()))`.  How can I get the list of the names of the objects in the global namespace (from within a module), so I can do my beautification?

I'm working in python3, if that matters.

EDIT:
The first two answers that came back had to do with my controlling code in the module containing `pretty`.  That's not what I want to do.  I'm aiming at an experience like the following.

```
>>> foo = create_something()
>>> bar = create_something_else()
>>> create_lots_more_stuff()
>>> # Hmmmm I'd like to see a list of all the things I have created in my interactive python session.
>>> pretty(dir())
foo     bar
baz     qux
etc     etc_etc
```

Comment: `globals()` gives you the global namespace, which *is the objects in the module*

Answer (score 4):

Rather than write a function to filter the `dir()` results, use the attributes `__all__` and/or `__dir__` to let your module publicly export the namespace explicitly, as described in [PEP 0562](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/).

```
# lib.py
deprecated_names = ["old_function", ...]
__all__ = ["new_function_one", "new_function_two", ...]

def new_function_one(arg, other):
   ...

def new_function_two(arg, other):
    ...

def __dir__():
    return sorted(__all__ + deprecated_names)
```

Usage:

```
# main.py
import lib

dir(lib)  # prints ["new_function_one", "new_function_two", "old_function", ...]
```

*Note:* The module level `__dir__` hook requires Python 3.7+.

---

**Edit:** Perhaps you will be interested in the [`who`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-who) and [`whos`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-whos) magic commands provided in an IPython interactive session. Demo shown below.

```
>>> who
Interactive namespace is empty.
>>> x = 123
>>> def foo():
...     pass
... 
... 
>>> who
foo  x   
>>> whos
Variable   Type        Data/Info
--------------------------------
foo        function    <function foo at 0x109b59158>
x          int         123
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this allows me to tell the rest of the world what's in my module.  I want my module to see what's in the rest of the world.

Comment: How is that any different from looking in `locals()` or `globals()`?

Comment: @wim the OP seems to be confused about the nature of the global namespace.

Comment: Yes, the OP is confused, and he appreciates your help alleviating his confusion.  One thing that might still be unclear is that the call to 'globals()' will be coming from inside the module, so IIUC it won't return the "globals" from the global namespace, but from the namespace of the module.

Comment: What difference is it? Usually when people talk about a global namespace, they are talking about the outermost namespace of a module. If you want any more help you'll have to clearly distinguish which global namespace you are referring to and how it differs from the module namespace.

Comment: I'm interested in the namespace that you occupy when you begin an interactive python session.  If that is not a 'namespace' then I'd be interested to learn the proper name.  In the example above, I want the function in my module, e.g.
```
def ls():
    pretty(globals()) # or pretty(dir())
```
 to list the names `foo` and `bar` (created and bound from the interactive python prompt) rather than the names of the things in my module.  I very much appreciate your help and I'm not trying to be difficult.  I'm just not sure how I can be more clear.

Comment: Hmm, that's not really possible, the interactive namespace is not visible when importing a module. Perhaps you should consider using an IPython interactive session, which provides a feature similar to what you're describing. Check the edited answer.