# Utility function that tries to delete a variable not working when put in a module

Tags: python, namespaces, ipython

I have a long ipynb file. I want to periodically clean namespace from variables that I do not need further in a notebook.

I wrote an utility function for that:

```py
def clean_namespace(variables_to_delete):
    deleted = []
    for variable in variables_to_delete:
        if variable in globals():
            del globals()[variable]
            deleted.append(variable)
    return deleted
```

The function works fine, it deletes all existing variables from the given list of variable names.

If I want to use it in multiple jupyter notebooks, it is logical to put its definition in a module, lets say `my_utils.py'.

However, if I try:

```py
from my_utils import clean_namespace
clean_namespace(['var1','var2'])
```

It does not delete anything, even if 'var1' exist in the notebook in the moment of calling.

I understood from [@Steven Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9221448/steven-scott)'s comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58070649/7745170) that globals() gives variables defined in the module where a function resists, but I find convenient to have such a function in my toolbox and not to have to define it again in each notebook.

Is there an elegant way to have this functionality?  Should I pass some additional argument?

Comment: Shouldn't you pass the reference to global() in the function itself as an argument?

Comment: @MukulBindal it may be, but I do not know how to do that.

Comment: try the solution I have provided in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather pass the scope in the function. Modify the code like this:

```
def clean_namespace(scope, variables_to_delete):
    deleted = []
    for variable in variables_to_delete:
        if variable in scope:
            del scope[variable]
            deleted.append(variable)
    return deleted
```

Then I will call it like this:

```
from my_utils import clean_namespace
clean_namespace(globals(), ['var1','var2'])
```

This will ensure that your variables are cleaned up from the scope of your module only.